# {0[Jack]:d} in Python .format(), What is the significance of the 'd'?

Tags: python

From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html),
I have a doubt in this part:

> If you have a really long format string that you don’t want to split
>   up, it would be nice if you could reference the variables to be
>   formatted by name instead of by position. This can be done by simply
>   passing the dict and using square brackets `'[]'` to access the keys
>
> ```
> table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 8637678}  
> print ('Jack: {0[Jack]:d}; Sjoerd: {0[Sjoerd]:d}; Dcab: {0[Dcab]:d}'.format(table))
> ```

What is the significance of the `d` in `{0[Jack]:d}`?

Comment: You should follow the links in the docs if you need more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to the [printf type field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field).
 As from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> 'd'   Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.

This may not seem terribly useful, given that only an integer can be specified. In fact, the default format for an integer is decimal.  But.  [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

With a complex format statement, it's helpful to have an *explicit* notation for a decimal integer.

Comment: do you know what is the meaning of zeros in the above expresion?

Comment: the zeros represent the first argument passed to `format()`. see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#simple-and-compound-field-names